# error when install tools in docker container

Tags: docker, installation, containers

I install ubuntu-14.04.4-server-amd64.iso in my VirtualBox,then I use some way to get its rootfs. after that i can the rootfs to create my docker image.the Dockerfile as following:

```
FROM scratch
COPY rootfs /
RUN chmod u+s /usr/bin/sudo && chmod u+s /bin/mount && chmod u+s /bin/umount
```

I start my docker container,then I install some tools,like minicom,wget ...,but error,the following is error msg:

```
root@20ca319c51e6:~$ apt-get install minicom 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
minicom is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up libpam-systemd:amd64 (204-5ubuntu20.19) ...
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/systemd-logind not found.
runlevel:/var/run/utmp: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package libpam-systemd:amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 100
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libpam-systemd:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I also try to "apt-get update；apt-get upgrade",but get same error msg too,
what's should i do.need you help! thanks all :)

Comment: your container does not have a proper init system include whatever you passed to `docker run ` is your init hence those errors, you probably want to explain what you intend doing that lead you to copying rootfs